# how to read value from XML?

Tags: c#, xml

The data:

```
<sys>
  <id>SCPUCLK</id>
  <label>CPU Clock</label>
  <value>2930</value>
</sys>
<sys>
  <id>CPUTEMP</id>
  <label>CPU Temp</label>
  <value>39</value>
</sys>
```

This is the code that I'm using to read the data:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(data);
XmlElement node = document.SelectSingleNode("/sys/value") as XmlElement;
Console.WriteLine("node = " + node);
```

The issue: `Console.WriteLine("node = " + node);` doesn't give me any output besides `node:` but no actual value like 2930 from the sample above.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to using XmlDocument, you can also use LINQ to XML (which is my preference):

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
// Parse loads the XDocument with XML from a string
xDoc = XDocument.Parse(data);

string node = (from x in xDoc.Root.Elements("value")
               select x.Value).SingleOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine("node = " + node);
```

Nothing wrong with using XmlDocument, especially for what you're doing, but you might want to check out LINQ to XML when you get a chance, as I find it a lot easier to work with than XmlDocument.

If you want to get all the "value" elements, simply remove the `SingleOrDefault()` from the query, and then you can loop through the result, like this:

```
var nodes = from x in xDoc.Root.Elements("value")
           select x.Value;

foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("node = " + node);
}
```

Here's a site worth checking out:
[LINQ to XML - 5 Minute Overview](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx)

Comment: you are simply AWESOME!!! thank you, i can finally move on with my Arduino project.

Comment: hey well that data that i showed first that only one of them element, their are multiple of them, i edited the first post to show what i meant.

Comment: @Csharpz - I updated my answer with what to do to get all the "value" nodes.  This is (to me) where LINQ to XML really starts to show its worth.  Also check out the site I linked to (I'm not affiliated with it in any way, but I used it extensively when I first started doing LINQ to XML about a year ago).

Comment: oh, thanks i got it anyways it was an issue with another part. but another quick questiong, this is a line from another code: var fragment = XNode.ReadFrom(fragmentReader) as XElement; how would i write the output to a string instead of a var?

Comment: The best way would be to loop through `fragment`, as XNode.ReadFrom returns an XNode that contains that node and any descendant nodes.  Similar to my 2nd example above.

Answer (score 4):

use node.value ie., XmlElement.value